# Simple Simulation of Time Dependent Dynamics

Tags: drake

So, I am wanting to simulate the dynamics of a system which varies over time.

Essentially:

`xdot = Q/C_a - x/(R_aC_a)`

where Q is an impulse train with period T. I estimate the solution by hand with some different techniques. But, I was curious if there was a simple way in drake to account for this time-dependence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time dependence is supported in basically every workflow -- even in the `SymbolicVectorSystem` that I know you have been using, you can define a variable for time and your dynamics method can depend on it.

An impulse train (in time), though, is a particular dependence on time that we need to think through.  These are often used as models of sampling/reconstruction (particularly useful in the frequency domain), but not very common in continuous-time simulation, I think?  I'm not sure you actually want to have that on your input?  If you do, then drake's event systems are probably up to the task, but first I want to check if it's really your intended workflow.

Comment: So, essentially. I define a time variable and define the system with that time variable. Then do I have to define something in the function which creates the system like `time = t`?

The impulse train is a function commonly used when simulating this model - the Windkessel Model. However, it does not need to explicitly be an impulse train. It can be a square wave or triangular wave. The only real requirement of this is that it mimics the activity of the heart. So we want some blood volume/current being sent to the system in regular pulses at some rate.

Comment: That’s correct.  SymbolicVectorSystem takes `time` as an optional argument: https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.systems.primitives.html#pydrake.systems.primitives.SymbolicVectorSystem_

Comment: Okay, great. Thank you!